# incluir una coordenada en el mapa en r

Tags: r

tengo el siguiente mapa de un pueblo y quisiera incluir una coordenada, como lo puedo hacer?. Gracias

El codigo es:

```
library(ggplot2)

s <- catr_atom_get_parcels("Galapagar", to = "Madrid",what ="parcel")

ggplot(s) + 
    geom_sf() + 
    labs(title = "Cadastral Zoning",subtitle = "Galapagar, Madrid")
```

saludos y gracias

Comment: ¡Hola! Te adjunto este enlace por si fuese de ayuda para tu pregunta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130604/plot-coordinates-on-map

Comment: Bienvenido gusilu a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes con el código que has compartido?

Comment: Buenas tardes, como incluir una coordenada (punto de localización) en el plano, teniendo coordenadas gps?- gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir un ejemplo de los datos GPS que quieres añadir?